# Update PivotTable Filter by Cell Input

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I am trying to update a filter in my pivot table (date) from 2 cell input (startdate, enddate), so that I set a startdate (e.g. 01/01/12) and an enddate (28/03/12) the pivot table will automatically apply a filter displaying just the dates within the range. 
For this purpose, I found some VBA code snippets on the internet:

```
Option Explicit

Sub FilterPivotDates()
'
Dim dStart As Date
Dim dEnd As Date
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pi As PivotItem

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error Resume Next

dStart = Sheets("Pivot").Range("StartDate").Value
dEnd = Sheets("Pivot").Range("EndDate").Value

Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTable2
Set pf = pt.PivotFields("Week")

pt.ManualUpdate = True

pf.EnableMultiplePageItems = True

For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
  pi.Visible = True
Next pi

For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
  If pi.Value < dStart Or pi.Value > dEnd Then
    pi.Visible = False
  End If
Next pi

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
pt.ManualUpdate = False

Set pf = Nothing
Set pt = Nothing

End Sub
```

I have that in the Modules folder of my worksheet and in Sheet "Pivot" I put "Option Explicit".
I assigned the range names "StartDate" and "EndDate" to the two cells with date input and assigned a button with the macro. The PivotTable is named "PivotTable" and the respective Field that should be filtered is named "Week". But when I hit the button nothing happens... Does someone see a error in the code or should I implement it differently?

Thanks upfront!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the final

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

to

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

It could be that you did everything properly but just can't see it :)  If that isn't the case (which it sounds like it wasn't), it could be that you aren't comparing similar types. This isn't an answer, but it may help figure out what is wrong: try placing some debug statements for the loop to determine the values/types in the input cells:

```
Debug.Print "dStart Value: " & dStart.Value
Debug.Print "dEnd Value: " & dEnd.Value
Debug.Print "dStart Type: " & VarType(dStart)
Debug.Print "dEnd Type: " & VarType(dEnd)
```

And then adding another check into your loop:

```
For Each Pi In pf.PivotItems
  Debug.Print "Pi Value: " & Pi.Value
  Debug.Print "Pi Type: " & VarType(Pi.Value)
  If Pi.Value < dStart Or Pi.Value > dEnd Then
    Pi.Visible = False
  End If
Next Pi
```

Again, not sure if this will reveal anything, but it could be that the code is working but not comparing anything. On that note, have you tried modifying the loop to verify that it is working by hard-coding a value to select? If that works, we can narrow it down a bit more.

Comment: Ha, figured it wouldn't be that easy. My only other thought for now is that perhaps you are comparing values that aren't of the same type (or in the same format)? I'll add some other stuff you can try to my (incorrect) answer.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the detailed answer! I must admit that I am more ov an VBA novice but I tried to follow what you said :) After insering the Debug MarkUps you send it gets an error when executing saying that there is an Invalid qualifier  for "dStart.Value" and Sub FilterPivotDates() is marked yellow

Comment: Ha, well you got everything started - that's pretty good. The basic idea (it looks like @scott is thinking the same thing) is that it may be your code works just fine, but it is trying to compare values that are different than what you're expecting. To use the `debug` stuff, open up the Editor (where you pasted the code), click on View and select Immediate Window. You should see a bunch of variable name/values printed there - if you see different stuff than you're expecting, that may be the issue.

Comment: Thanks! ..hm there is nothing printed there. That is quite strange

Comment: Alright, well that narrows it down a bit - it sounds like it isn't running at all. Happy to go into chat if you want, but just in case - have you verified that macros are enabled? Sometimes your workbook can have macros turned off without notification, meaning it simply won't run.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15436/discussion-between-rocketdonkey-and-user1507035)

Comment: hm I know did everything in a new sheet (I think an other makro messed this one up) and now it at least filters the (blank) entries from the list but not the correct date range... But at least we now know that the makro itself is applied. Any other ideas?

Comment: Sure, I'll drop them into that chat link and we can continue it there (since our time zones don't quite overlap :) ).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your problem is in your dstart and dend.  By getting the value I believe it changes the date to the excel numerical value.

try changing this line:

```
    If pi.Value < dStart Or pi.Value > dEnd Then
```

to something like:

```
    If cdate(pi.value)< cdate(dStart) Or cdate(pi.value) > cdate(dend) then
```

if that doesn't work try only putting the cdate on your two created variables